# How to use git index to test if change works?

Tags: git

While I understand that git index if useful when doing complex merges by staging many smaller hunks, I do not understand why non-merges should or need to go through index. Consider example below.

I work on a project and make changes in many files. Some I intend to commit, some might be only temporary used during debugging (e.g. tracing statements). Once the feature is complete, I need to make a commit. Now, let's assume I make a mistake by not staging all necessary changes and the commit is broken. Unless I checkout staged changes somewhere and re-compile and re-test (not quite a productive approach in my opinion), I don't even know about the problem and will have to rewrite that commit later.

It leads me to think that maybe I should compile and test only staged content and it would be easier if that would be equal to the working copy itself. The problem of untracked files remains though.

How should one use index to ensure staged changes are good?

Comment: You can remove all of your temporary work with `git stash` (recover with `git stash apply`). Leaves the problem of untracked files, but well …

Comment: @knittl Have a look at `git stash save -u`.

Answer (score 3):

> *Unless I checkout staged changes somewhere and re-compile and re-test (not quite a productive approach in my opinion)*

This is very productive. It's known as ["continuous integration testing"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) or CI. It's considered best practice. CI servers can be found for free these days including [TravisCI](http://travis-ci.org/), [GitLab CI](https://about.gitlab.com/gitlab-ci/), and [AppVeyor](http://appveyor.com/) for Windows testing.

CI ensures a clean copy of the code is tested in a clean environment. This catches the sort of problem you mentioned, forgetting to commit something, and a host of others. It also avoids any assumptions based on your particular development machine like any dependencies you forgot to declare.

CI can run various combinations of operating systems, compilers, and dependencies that your users might encounter. It also makes it easier to contribute and accept contributions because the CI server ensures those contributions are tested.

And, perhaps most importantly, it ensures the tests are run. People forget sometimes, or get lazy.

---

> *I work on a project and make changes in many files. Some I intend to commit, some might be only temporary used during debugging (e.g. tracing statements).*

You want it so that when you run `git status` anything it says is to be staged. Then there is no need to carefully examine `git status` to figure out what is and is not to be staged. This greatly reduces the chance of missing something (or accidentally committing something).

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

First is to make judicious use of [`.gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) to ignore any files which are not to be committed. This includes build artifacts and local configuration files.

Second is to avoid habitually having hand written debugging statements that you carry around from commit to commit. It's *really* easy to accidentally commit them, and other developers don't benefit from them. Instead, use a debugging flag and leave them in. Flip the debugging flag on as needed.

---

> *It leads me to think that maybe I should compile and test only staged content and it would be easier if that would be equal to the working copy itself. The problem of untracked files remains though.*

This is a good idea. You can do it by [stashing your changes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Stashing-and-Cleaning). The stash is a little side place to store work in progress, sort of like saving patch file. The basic workflow is...

```
# Save all changes except what is staged
$ git stash save -ku

...do your testing on the staged change...

# If it worked, commit the change.
$ git commit

# Restore your unstaged changes and untracked files.
$ git stash pop
```

`-k` says to keep whatever is already staged. `-u` says to stash untracked files as well.

---

In general, any process that requires everyone to be careful all the time will fail. Continuous Integration means you can't forget to run the tests, or run them in a certain environment. Keeping your working directory clean means people don't have to carefully examine what to stage or not stage, they can habitually stage everything. People can pound on `git add .` and `git commit -a` and be reasonably sure it's the right thing.